# Reactive variable that automatically updates all tabs on change?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I need a reactive local variable that persists across page refreshes, is unique to a browser and is reactive across all tabs in that one browser. Persistent session or reactive local storage doesn't work, because if a change occurs in one tab, it isn't recognized in the other tab until you refresh a page.

I am currently trying with grounddb collection, but it isn't bulletproof and may sometimes not register a change or revert back to old one. Is there a better way to achieve this behaviour?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used http://plugins.jquery.com/storageapi/ in combination with Tracker.dependancy to achieve reactivity and sessionStorage (tab unique) / localStorage (browser unique) variables.

Comment: Curious if you have an example, I'm working on the same thing except via amplify. Right now I have the localStorage acting reactively within a tab, but not within the entire browser, that still is requiring a reset.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome 37 on my machine, window.localStorage does sync between tabs. I'm not sure about other browsers though and it wouldn't be reactive automatically if you used that method.

You are probably best off using a collection with documents assigned by user ID, then you can rely on Meteor's reactivity.

Comment: [browser-store](https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/browser-store) gives a reactive interface to local storage (also uses some weird IE-specific thing for IE6/7) which they claim works across tabs. Unfortunately it hasn't been updated for Meteor 0.9; in fact it hasn't seen a commit since January last year.